# Eclipse java - How do I include Jersey archetype in Maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, jersey

I am trying to create a Webapp using Maven Jersey archetype, but while I am searching it, it's not giving me any result.

Can you please if I need to set up anything for this or how do I get the search result for this?

**Expected:**
[image]

**Actual:**

[image]

Comment: See https://howtodoinjava.com/tools/eclipse/how-to-import-maven-remote-archetype-catalogs-in-eclipse/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the Jersey Maven Archetype to your Eclipse because your catalog is not the lastest version.

Go to **Preferences -> Maven -> Archetypes ->Add Remote Catalog** and add these parameters:

```
Catalog File: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
Description: maven catalog
```

> Note: Probably It's necesary to restart your Eclipse.

Comment: Works for me without restarting Eclipse (in the status line it is displayed when reception of the catalog has completed).

Comment: Worked ! Thanks!

Comment: UPDATE : Use https instead of http

Answer (score 1):

The update one is :

1. Go to Preferences -> Maven -> Archetypes ->Add Remote Catalog and
   add these parameters:
2. Catalog File:
   **https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml**
3. Description: **maven catalog**

Click on verify to check the remote link.

**Note:  restart your Eclipse**

Source:https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-catalog/archetype-catalog.html

The Archetype Plugin knows by default its internal catalog. It also knows about the local and remote catalogs:

local represents the **~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml catalog file**,

remote represents the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml catalog file.