# tomcat 8.0 failed to start while running a simple jersey program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jersey, restful-architecture

I am frustrated with this issue. Tried all possible solution available on Internet but still no luck.

While I am running this code tomcat is not able to start and getting failed every time. Please help

[image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, 
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html#d4e194 -->

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.restapp.jerseyapp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/jersey/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**code:**

```
package com.restapp.jerseyapp;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

/** Example resource class hosted at the URI path "/myresource"
 */
@Path("/hi")
public class MyResource {

    /** Method processing HTTP GET requests, producing "text/plain" MIME media
     * type.
     * @return String that will be send back as a response of type "text/plain".
     */
    @GET 
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getIt() {
        return "Hi there!";
    }
}
```

[image]

**Console output**

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.47
Oct 09, 2017 8:20:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jerseyapp]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you change localhost to localhost:8080, and check the logs.

Comment: You should be checking (and posting) the output from the Console view as well.

Comment: Changed that loacalhost to localhost:8080 but no luck, updated the console error.

Comment: @nitind -- see the error

Comment: Don't truncate it. The full log output is what's needed.

Comment: How are you building the war? Did you included the jersey dependencies inside the war file?

Comment: @Rishikesh Darandale I am simply running it on server from eclipse right click on app > run as ). May know what dependency you are taking about and how to add it ?

Comment: @nitind it's not allowing me to add the whole error output

Comment: @Rajarshi, Are you using maven to create the jersey project? If not, then you need to add `jersey-server` jar and other dependencies of it in your eclipse build path. In maven it will be a lot quicker than manually adding them to the build path.

Comment: Btw, you are using `jersey1`. You can use `jersey2` and follow [this](http://www.javarticles.com/2015/12/jersey-restful-quick-start-example.html) for more details.

Comment: Now, I see looks like you are creating the project using `jersey2` archtype as described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46646253/eclipse-java-how-do-i-include-jersey-archetype-in-maven) and coding it in `jersey1`. Please update your code to `jersey2`

Comment: @ Rishikesh Darandale thanks for all your help. I have fixed it. I guess I selected wrong jersey archetype while creating this project

Answer (score 0):

I too had same problem.  I fixed this problem by removing jersey jars from my local maven repo and then freshly installed same jars.

```
C:\Users\{user}\.m2\repository\com\sun\jersey
```

After doing above steps, please do maven install .